# Copy a list to a different list where both have other classes in

Tags: c#

I have the following classes

```
namespace A;
public ClassA
{
     public int A {get;set;} 
     public string B {get;set;}
     public List<typeA> TypeA {get;set;}
     public TypeB TypeB {get;set;}
}

public class typeA
{ // properties }

public class TypeB
{ // properties }

namespace B;
public ClassB
{
     public string BB {get;set;}
     public List<A.typeA> TypeA {get;set;}
}
```

I'm trying to copy from A.ClassA into B.ClassB.

The code I'm using to copy the data from is this

```
public class CopyClass
{
    public static void CopyObject<T>(object sourceObject, ref T destObject)
    {
        if (sourceObject == null || destObject == null)
            return;

        Type sourceType = sourceObject.GetType();
        Type targetType = destObject.GetType();

        //  Loop through the source properties
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in sourceType.GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo targetObj = targetType.GetProperty(p.Name);
            //  If there is none, skip
            if (targetObj == null)
                continue;

            try
            {
                if (p.GetType() == targetObj.GetType())
                    targetObj.SetValue(destObject, p.GetValue(sourceObject, null), null);
                    * exception thrown for non-primitives
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception copying : ex.Message = {ex.Message}, inner = {ex.InnerException?.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue comes when I try to copy the non-primitive types (an exception is thrown at * in the code above). Is it possible to do a deep copy so I can just copy the corresponding properties in ClassA and ClassB including the collections?

Comment: If the object can be serialized to something like json or xml then you can serialize it, then deserialize it to make a deep copy.

Comment: FYI: This code is not affected by whether you are using xamarin or maui or something else entirely, so I have removed those tags as not relevant.

Comment: Using reflection for this, is not very performant. It also doesn't read so nice. Just write a mapper, or use something like automapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As p and targetObj are both PropertyInfo type,

```
if (p.GetType() == targetObj.GetType())
```

always returns true. So you will mismatch types.
Use

```
if (p.PropertyType == targetObj.PropertyType)
```